# Is there any restriction for Python WinRM PowerShell response?

Tags: python, powershell, winrm

I do a `Get-DhcpServer4Leases` on our main DHCP server.
The response is quite huge and I do a `convert_to_json` on server side.
But for me it looks like the response is cut in the middle and I only get only the first 3M chars.

Is there any response limitation on Python Windows or in the middle?
Can I change the limit to fit more to our needs?

Comment: client is  on linux ....

Comment: `3M chars` -- 3 million!?

Comment: For help with your code: show your code.

Comment: Is it cut on the server side or the client side? Please show how you're calling. How is python involved? Why use python json conversion when powershell has ConvertTo-Json?

Comment: I run  
`ps_cmd = 'Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName ' + dmc + ' -ScopeId 0.0.0.0' `   


`r = winrm_session.run_ps(ps_cmd + ' | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1 ')   `